# How can I wrap the results from a MySQL query to the next line on the terminal?

Tags: mysql, sql, macos, terminal, mamp

[image]When returning results that have are long in their string length, the terminal doesn't show the entire row. I would ideally like them to wrap to the next line so that I can see the full thing

Comment: Dont know about wrapping but you can see them in a different way by using /G at the end of query.

Comment: That doesn't work. Already tried it.